# MongoDB Aggregate two different groups

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have data set and i need two diffrent group by values from that data set. please find the data set below,

```
[{
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411772",
    "STATUS": 1,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-21T04:10:23.000Z")
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411772",
    "STATUS": 4,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-22T04:10:23.000Z")
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411772",
    "STATUS": 4,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-23T04:10:23.000Z")
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411774",
    "STATUS": 3,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-24T04:10:23.000Z")
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322311",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411775",
    "STATUS": 1,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-25T04:10:23.000Z")
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322311",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411775",
    "STATUS": 3,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-23T04:10:23.000Z")
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322322",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411774",
    "STATUS": 1,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-20T04:10:23.000Z")
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322322",
    "SPEC_ID": "58411778",
    "STATUS": 4,
    "UPDATE_DATE": ISODate("2016-12-21T04:10:23.000Z")
  }
]
```

I want to group this by using **ASSIGN_ID** and **STATUS** and also inside each **ASSIGN_ID** group I need **SPEC_ID** and also by **STATUS**. please find the expected output below,

```
[{
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322398",
    "ASSIGN_GROUP": [{
        "STATUS": 1,
        "COUNT": 1
      },
      {
        "STATUS": 3,
        "COUNT": 1
      },
      {
        "STATUS": 4,
        "COUNT": 2
      }
    ],
    "SPEC_ARRAY": [{
        "SPEC_ID": "58411772",
        "SPEC_GROUP": [{
            "STATUS": 1,
            "COUNT": 1
          },
          {
            "STATUS": 4,
            "COUNT": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "SPEC_ID": "58411774",
        "SPEC_GROUP": [{
          "STATUS": 3,
          "COUNT": 1
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322311",
    "ASSIGN_GROUP": [{
        "STATUS": 1,
        "COUNT": 1
      },
      {
        "STATUS": 3,
        "COUNT": 1
      }
    ],
    "SPEC_ARRAY": [{
      "SPEC_ID": "58411775",
      "SPEC_GROUP": [{
          "STATUS": 1,
          "COUNT": 1
        },
        {
          "STATUS": 3,
          "COUNT": 1
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "ASSIGN_ID": "583f84bce58725f76b322322",
    "ASSIGN_GROUP": [{
        "STATUS": 1,
        "COUNT": 1
      },
      {
        "STATUS": 4,
        "COUNT": 1
      }
    ],
    "SPEC_ARRAY": [{
        "SPEC_ID": "58411774",
        "SPEC_GROUP": [{
          "STATUS": 1,
          "COUNT": 1
        }]
      },
      {
        "SPEC_ID": "58411778",
        "SPEC_GROUP": [{
          "STATUS": 4,
          "COUNT": 1
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

currently, what I did so far is just group the **ASSIGN_ID** and by **STATUS** please find the code below,

```
Modal.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "INSPECTED_BY": "$INSPECTED_BY",
        "STATUS": "$STATUS"
      },
      "spec_id": "$SPEC_ID",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.INSPECTED_BY",
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "STATUS": "$_id.STATUS",
          "total": "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

and the result is

```
[
  {
    "_id": "583f84bce58725f76b322398",
    "data": [
      {
        "STATUS": 1,
        "COUNT": 1
      }, {
        "STATUS": 3,
        "COUNT": 1
      }, {
        "STATUS": 4,
        "COUNT": 2
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "_id": "583f84bce58725f76b322311",
    "data": [
      {
        "STATUS": 1,
        "COUNT": 1
      }, {
        "STATUS": 3,
        "COUNT": 1
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "_id": "583f84bce58725f76b322322",
    "data": [
      {
        "STATUS": 1,
        "COUNT": 1
      }, {
        "STATUS": 4,
        "COUNT": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

please, provide me a suitable solution get the expected result.

Comment: What is your mongo server version ?

Comment: Version is : 3.2.1

Answer (score 2):

You can try the alternative aggregation below for version 3.2.

```
Modal.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            ASSIGN_ID: "$ASSIGN_ID",
            SPEC_ID: "$SPEC_ID",
            STATUS: "$STATUS"
        },
        COUNT: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            ASSIGN_ID: "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
            SPEC_ID: "$_id.SPEC_ID"
        },
        SPEC_GROUP: {
            $push: {
                STATUS: "$_id.STATUS",
                COUNT: "$COUNT"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
        SPEC_ARRAY: {
            $push: {
                SPEC_ID: "$_id.SPEC_ID",
                SPEC_GROUP: "$SPEC_GROUP"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        ASSIGN_ID: "$_id",
        ASSIGN_GROUP: "$SPEC_ARRAY.SPEC_GROUP",
        SPEC_ARRAY: 1
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$ASSIGN_GROUP"
}, {
    $unwind: "$ASSIGN_GROUP"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$ASSIGN_ID",
        ASSIGN_GROUP: {
            $push: "$ASSIGN_GROUP"
        },
        SPEC_ARRAY: {
            $first: "$SPEC_ARRAY"
        }
    }
}])
```

Replace last four stages with `$reduce`for version 3.4

```
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        ASSIGN_ID: "$_id",
        SPEC_ARRAY: 1,
        ASSIGN_GROUP: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$SPEC_ARRAY.SPEC_GROUP",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a multi-pass pipeline; if required to fetch two different sets of grouping within same pass; will have to group for one set first. Once that set is arrived, keep the data required for next set of grouping.

Pipeline involved:
`group` :(1) Group By ASSIGN_ID, SPEC_ID, STATUS - get the count for this combination
`group` :(2) Group By ASSIGN_ID, SPEC_ID - prepare SPEC_GROUP Array
`group` :(3) Group By ASSIGN_ID - prepare SPEC_ARRAY Array of objects
`project` : Select ASSIGN_ID, SPEC_ARRAY, a copy of SPEC_ARRAY data for preparing grouping by STATUS 
`unwind` : Unwind SPEC Array elements to get data for each spec_id separated 
`unwind` : Unwind SPEC Array. SPEC_GROUP elements to get data for each spec_id /status separated 
`group` :(4) Group By ASSIGN_ID,STATUS - get the count per status [When getting the count ADD counts corresponding to each status since we already grouped by SPEC_ID], select SPEC_ARRAY from first row as that is repeating all across
`group` :(5) Group By ASSIGN_ID - get the assign group array, select SPEC_ARRAY from first row as that is repeating all across

```
db.Modal.aggregate([ {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            ASSIGN_ID : "$ASSIGN_ID",
            SPEC_ID : "$SPEC_ID",
            STATUS : "$STATUS"
        },
        a_s_cnt : {
            $sum : 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            ASSIGN_ID : "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
            SPEC_ID : "$_id.SPEC_ID"
        },
        SPEC_GROUP : {
            $push : {
                STATUS : "$_id.STATUS",
                COUNT : "$a_s_cnt"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
        SPEC_ARRAY : {
            $push : {
                SPEC_ID : "$_id.SPEC_ID",
                SPEC_GROUP : "$SPEC_GROUP"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        ASSIGN_ID : "$_id",
        SPEC_ARRAY : "$SPEC_ARRAY",
        forStatus : "$SPEC_ARRAY"
    }
}, {
    $unwind : "$forStatus"
}, {
    $unwind : "$forStatus.SPEC_GROUP"
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : {
            ASSIGN_ID : "$ASSIGN_ID",
            STATUS : "$forStatus.SPEC_GROUP.STATUS"
        },
        statusCount : {
            $sum : "$forStatus.SPEC_GROUP.COUNT"
        },
        SPEC_ARRAY : {
            $first : "$SPEC_ARRAY"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
        ASSIGN_GROUP : {
            $push : {
                STATUS : "$_id.STATUS",
                COUNT : "$statusCount"
            }
        },
        SPEC_ARRAY : {
            $first : "$SPEC_ARRAY"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        ASSIGN_ID : "$_id",
        ASSIGN_GROUP : "$ASSIGN_GROUP",
        SPEC_ARRAY : "$SPEC_ARRAY"
    }
} ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Aggregate Command, Tested with your Sample data,

```
        db.test.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            ASSIGN_ID: "$ASSIGN_ID",
            STATUS: "$STATUS",
            SPEC_ID: "$SPEC_ID"
        },
        count: {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
        ASSIGN_GROUP: {
            $push: {
                STATUS: "$_id.STATUS",
                count: "$count"
            }
        },
        SPEC_ARRAY: {
            $push: {
                SPEC_ID: "$_id.SPEC_ID",
                STATUS: "$_id.STATUS",
                count: "$count"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$SPEC_ARRAY"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            ASSIGN_ID: "$_id",
            SPEC_ID: "$SPEC_ARRAY.SPEC_ID"
        },
        ASSIGN_GROUP: {
            $first: "$ASSIGN_GROUP"
        },
        SPEC_GROUP: {
            $push: {
                "STATUS": "$SPEC_ARRAY.STATUS",
                count: "$SPEC_ARRAY.count"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.ASSIGN_ID",
        ASSIGN_GROUP: {
            $first: "$ASSIGN_GROUP"
        },
        SPEC_ARRAY: {
            $push: {
                SPEC_ID: "$_id.SPEC_ID",
                SPEC_GROUP: "$SPEC_GROUP"
            }
        }
    }
}

]).pretty()
```